# I sent a token to a contract address by mistake. can I recover, and how to recover if I can

Tags: transactions, wallets, addresses

I sent some CryptoPunk Tokens to it's contract address, while I was traying to move it to my trust wallet from coinbase wallet. Here is the details of the transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa38b182326b723814cdd86204a6a6aea0fe82a59995a736572d1eb716c917815

Is there a way to recover? If it is how can I do it? I have tried looking into the website of the token, but it does not have any contact email. How can one contact these token creators? here is a link to the token website https://www.app.unic.ly/#/utoken-contract/0x8d2bffcbb19ff14a698c424fbcdcfd17aab9b905

Answer (score 0):

The contract that received the tokens does not have roles that withdraw tokens from itself or deny receipt of tokens.

I can say this is a serious security breach and oversight of the contract and code engineers. Negligence of the devs.

So even if they try it is impossible to recover the funds. There is no means of recovering contract funds after being deployed on mainnet.

Should you or anyone else find any relevant information or solution in the future, please be sure to share it here for the benefit of the entire crypto community.

---

And if that answer answered all your questions, please be sure to mark it as the best answer as a form of recognition.